# How to ignore an aggregation stage depending on a condition?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am working on fetching data from MongoDB using its Java driver. I am trying to add the filter data to my query when it is not null only. If the filters data is null at that time it is returning null values, as it is not able to find data satisfying the query due to that filters is null. But the concept is to exclude that filters data and proceed with the remaining where conditions like `BELONGS_TO_OWNER_DSID`, `IS_DELETED` only.

I have tried using `match(ne(filter, null))`, but it shows compilation error.

```
List<Bson> filters = new ArrayList<Bson>();
if (valueOfMonth != 0) {
    filters.add(gt(TECHNOLOGY_VERSION_EOL_KEY, LocalDate.now()));
    filters.add(lt(TECHNOLOGY_VERSION_EOL_KEY, getFutureDate(valueOfMonth)));
}
Map<String, Object> multiIdMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
multiIdMap.put(APPLICATION, "$application");
multiIdMap.put(TECHNOLOGY, "$technology");

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
AggregateIterable<Document> result = technologiesCollection.aggregate(
        Arrays.asList(
            match(eq(BELONGS_TO_OWNER_DSID, dsId)), 
            match(eq(IS_DELETED, false)),
            match(and(filters)),
            project(Projections.include(TECHNOLOGY, APPLICATION)), 
            group(multiIdMap, Accumulators.sum("count", 1)),
            sort(eq("count", 1)), 
            addFields(new Field("data", "$_id")), 
            project(eq("_id", 0))), 
        Document.class);
```

The expected result is, if `valueOfMonth=0`, then I don't want to have that filter data in the where query but use the rest like `BELONGS_TO_OWNER_DSID`, `IS_DELETED` fields only and give the entire result.

The filters data is to filter only if `valueOfMonth` is greater than zero, but if it is zero then return all values which match `BELONGS_TO_OWNER_DSID`, `IS_DELETED` only, without `valueOfMonth`.

The code is working as expected if I give `valueOfMonth>0`. However with 0, it will return null, as it is not able to find data satisfying the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing the following;

```
List<Document> aggregationList = new ArrayList()<>;
aggregationList.add(match(eq(BELONGS_TO_OWNER_DSID, dsId)));
aggregationList.add(match(eq(IS_DELETED, false)));
if (valueOfMonth != 0) {
    List<Bson> filters = new ArrayList<Bson>();
    filters.add(gt(TECHNOLOGY_VERSION_EOL_KEY, LocalDate.now()));
    filters.add(lt(TECHNOLOGY_VERSION_EOL_KEY, getFutureDate(valueOfMonth)));
    aggregationList.add(match(and(filters)));
}

aggregationList.add(project(Projections.include(TECHNOLOGY, APPLICATION)));
// add other stages...

AggregateIterable<Document> result = coll.aggregate(aggregationList, Document.class);
```

when `valueOfMonth == 0`, you won't have `match(and(filters))` in your aggregation list at all. Thus no need to try to utilize MongoDB driver to disable the `filters` logic, it will be just ignored in that case.

Comment: List<Bson> filters = new ArrayList<Bson>();
  filters.add(eq(BELONGS_TO_OWNER_DSID, dsId));
  filters.add(eq(IS_DELETED, false));
  if (valueOfMonth != 0) {
   filters.add(gt(TECHNOLOGY_VERSION_EOL_KEY, LocalDate.now()));
   filters.add(lt(TECHNOLOGY_VERSION_EOL_KEY, getFutureDate(valueOfMonth)));
  }

Comment: @user10382836 oh yeah, that is also a nice way to do it, do an `and()` of all conditions and filter the two with if check.